# Generate random string based on Regex?

Tags: ruby, regex, string, random

I wonder if there is a way to generate random string from a regex like:

```
/[a-z0-9]{5}/.to_s
#=> "dsar3"
```

I found `randexp` (https://github.com/benburkert/randexp) but it seems to not work with a basic example like above and anyway I feel it's left abandoned.

Anyone?

Comment: @iAmRubuuu This is not really random and is determined by a pattern instead.

Comment: It would need some basic constraints, right?  I mean, there's no way to generate a random regex that matchs `/.*/`, since the number of characters involved could be any length between 0 an infinite.  Should the *number* of characters be random also, or should we be trying to randomly select a value from an infinite set?  Or are you suggesting a constraint wherein the regex could not allow things like * or + (as is the case with your example)?

Comment: Also, if you had `.to_s` on a regex provide a random matching string, that'd be a pretty serious wtf for the next developer that saw that code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perl has a CPAN module that can do this. It works by converting the regex into a generative grammar. The concept can probably be adapted to Ruby, but would be a little work.

See http://metacpan.org/pod/Parse::RandGen and http://metacpan.org/pod/Parse::RandGen::Regexp

Answer (score 2):

No but how about:

```
(0..255).map(&:chr).select{|x| x =~ /[a-z0-9]/}.sample(5).join
#=> "qif0l"
```

Comment: what the `x =~ /[a-z0-9]/` is doing logically?

Comment: It's selecting only chars that match the regex

Comment: `sample` does not allow duplicates, so "qqf01" would never happen.

Comment: Well there's a simple workaround if you really need duplicates.