# Generate string for Regex pattern in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, string, random

In Python language I find [rstr](https://bitbucket.org/leapfrogdevelopment/rstr/) that can generate a string for a [regex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) pattern.

Or in Python we have this method that can return range of string:

```
re.sre_parse.parse(pattern)
#..... ('range', (97, 122)) ....
```

But In Ruby I didn't find any thing.

So how to generate string for a regex pattern in Ruby(reverse regex)?

I wanna to some thing like this:

```
"/[a-z0-9]+/".example
#tvvd
"/[a-z0-9]+/".example
#yt
"/[a-z0-9]+/".example
#bgdf6
"/[a-z0-9]+/".example
#564fb
```

**"/[a-z0-9]+/"** is my input.
The outputs must be correct string that available in my regex pattern.
Here outputs were: **tvvd , yt , bgdf6 , 564fb** that "example" method generated them.
I need that method.

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate random string based on Regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15859793/generate-random-string-based-on-regex)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Ruby:

```
/qweqwe/.to_s
# => "(?-mix:qweqwe)"
```

When you declare a `Regexp`, you've got the `Regexp` class object, to convert it to `String` class object, you may use `Regexp`'s method [`#to_s`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Regexp.html#method-i-to_s). During conversion the special fields will be expanded, as you may see in the example., using:

> (using the (?opts:source) notation. This string can be fed back in to Regexp::new to a regular expression with the same semantics as the original.

Also, you can use `Regexp`'s method [`#inspect`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Regexp.html#method-i-inspect), which:

> produces a generally more readable version of rxp.

```
/ab+c/ix.inspect        #=> "/ab+c/ix"
```

**Note:** that the above methods are only use for plain conversion `Regexp` into `String`, and in order to match or select set of string onto an other one, we use other methods. For example, if you have a sourse array (or string, which you wish to split with `#split` method), you can grep it, and get result array:

```
array = "test,ab,yr,OO".split( ',' )
# => ['test', 'ab', 'yr', 'OO']

array = array.grep /[a-z]/
 # => ["test", "ab", "yr"]
```

And then convert the array into string as:

```
array.join(',')
# => "test,ab,yr"
```

Or just use `#scan` method, with slightly changed regexp:

```
"test,ab,yr,OO".scan( /[a-z]+/ )
# => ["test", "ab", "yr"]
```

However, if you really need a random string matched the regexp, you have to write your own method, please refer to the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/88311/how-best-to-generate-a-random-string-in-ruby), or use [*ruby-string-random*](https://github.com/repeatedly/ruby-string-random) library. The library:

> generates a random string based on Regexp syntax or Patterns.

And the code will be like to the following:

```
pattern = '[aw-zX][123]'
result = StringRandom.random_regex(pattern)
```

Comment: Can you explain me how to use it?

Comment: thanks for your replay , can you take an example how to generate string? means when I tell /[a-z]/.... => it shows me for example "test,ab,yr,..."

Comment: @MortezaIpo  Generally no, because you dont have source for selection, it just convert the regexp into string, but if you have a sourse array, you can grep it, and get result array: `['test', 'ab', 'yr', 'OO'].grep /[a-z]/ # => ["test", "ab", "yr"]` and then convert the array into string as: `array.join(',')`

Comment: @MortezaIpo if my naswer is that you didn't wish, please update your questions woth a proper examples: what you have, and what do you wish in a result.

Comment: @MortezaIpo I really don't understand, which is your input condition. For example, I have the string, I should apply something rule to get other string. I see the rule, and I see the output, but don't see the input.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45089/discussion-between-morteza-ipo-and-majioa)

Comment: @MortezaIpo  So you need a random string matched to a the specific regexp?

Comment: Yes! exactly! random string generator for my regex pattern.

Comment: @MortezaIpo i've updated the post; please refer to the library.

Answer (score 11):

You can also use the Faker gem https://github.com/stympy/faker and then use this call:

```
 Faker::Base.regexify(/[a-z0-9]{10}/)
```

Answer (score 8):

A bit late to the party, but - originally inspired by this stackoverflow thread - I have created a powerful ruby gem which solves the original problem:

https://github.com/tom-lord/regexp-examples

```
/this|is|awesome/.examples #=> ['this', 'is', 'awesome']
/https?:\/\/(www\.)?github\.com/.examples #=> ['http://github.com', 'http://www.github.com', 'https://github.com', 'https://www.github.com']
```

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: Now regular expressions supported in string_pattern gem and it is 30 times faster than other gems

```
require 'string_pattern'
/[a-z0-9]+/.generate
```

To see a comparison of speed https://repl.it/@tcblues/Comparison-generating-random-string-from-regular-expression

---

I created a simple way to generate strings using a pattern without the mess of regular expressions, take a look at the string_pattern gem project: https://github.com/MarioRuiz/string_pattern

To install it: `gem install string_pattern`

This is an example of use:

```
# four characters. optional: capitals and numbers, required: lower
"4:XN/x/".gen    # aaaa, FF9b, j4em, asdf, ADFt
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can find what you are looking for over [here](http://rubyquiz.com/quiz143.html).

Comment: Inspired largely by this bit of code, I have created a gem which does everything discussed there (and much more): https://github.com/tom-lord/regexp-examples