# Find strings that match two regular expressions

Tags: ruby, regex

The two regexes:

```
regex_1 = /^A+\S{2}$/
regex_2 = /^AB+\d{1}$/
```

match the following ten strings:

```
AB0
AB1
AB2
AB3
AB4
AB5
AB6
AB7
AB8
AB9
```

Is there a way to find strings that match two regular expressions that are given?

---

I have a regex, and it will be sliced to many sub-regexes as follows.

Example 1:

```
original_regex = /^A+\S{2}$/
sub_regex1 = /^AB+\S{1}$/
sub_regex2 = /^AC+\S{1}$/
```

Example 2:

```
original_regex = /^598+\S{5}$/
sub_regex1 = /^598A+\S{4}$/
sub_regex2 = /^598AB+\S{3}$/
```

I want to know whether there are any strings that match all sub-regexes.

I am thinking to convert the regex to a string and compare the minimal-length prefix and the minimal-length suffix like this:

```
regex_1 = "/^A+\S{2}$/"
regex_2 = "/^AB+\d{1}$/"
regex_3 = "/^AC+\d{1}$/"
minimal_prefix = "/^A"
```

Any regex string that contains `minimal_prefix` has a string that matches all sub-regexes. I am figuring out whether this is correct or not.

Comment: maybe related [generate string for regex pattern in ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21084246/generate-string-for-regex-pattern-in-ruby)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a quick way **in general**? No. What are "all the strings" that match these pairs of regular expressions:

- `/.*/` and `/\d*/`? (There are *infinitely* many!)
- `/\A\d{10}\z/` and `/\A[0-8]{10}\z/`? (There are 3,486,784,401!)
- `/\w+\d{2,4}@?([[:punct:]]|\w){2}/` and `/(^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$)/` (I haven't even tried to work this out; my point is: you could provide arbitrarily complicated input!!)

...But for *simple* scenarios, such as what you've actually asked, it would be feasible to use [this ruby gem](https://github.com/tom-lord/regexp-examples):

```
/^A+\S{2}$/.examples(max_group_results: 999) & /^AB+\d{1}$/.examples(max_group_results: 999)
=> ["AB0", "AB1", "AB2", "AB3", "AB4", "AB5", "AB6", "AB7", "AB8", "AB9"]
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try this gem. I will update my question to clarify my situation

Comment: Regarding your edit: *"Any regex string that contains `minimal_prefix` has a string that matches all sub-regexes. I am figuring out whether this is correct or not."* --- Again, this works in **simple** scenarios, but *not in general!!!* Here's a trivial example: `/a|b+/` vs `/b+/` -- by your logic, there are *no* strings that match both, when in reality there are clearly infinitely many (`"b"`, `"bb"`, `"bbb"`, `"bbbb"`, ...).

Comment: So, again: If you de-scope the problem to simple scenarios like this, then you could write an efficient solution quite easily. But it's **not** easy to solve the problem *in general*.