# rspec model test on string match regex adjustment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have the following test in rspec

```
  it 'passes regex rules' do
    job = create(:job)
    job.valid?
    expect(job.title).to match(/\A[\w\d .,:-@]+\z/)
  end
```

This regex pattern matches the model pattern.  What is the recommended way to test to make sure this pattern does not change in the model from future developers?

Basically I want to test for conditions that do not fall in the approved: `can only have 0-9, A-Z, periods, colons, hypens, underscores, and spaces. No new lines (enter keys)`

**Update**

Based on [Generate random string based on Regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15859793/generate-random-string-based-on-regex) I decided to go with `(0..255).map(&:chr).select{|x| x != /\A[\w\d .,:-@]+\z/}.sample(5).join` for now which appears to work, thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the update, I went with the following:

```
describe 'title' do
  let(:bad_string) { (0..255).map(&:chr).select{|x| x != /\A[\w\d .,:-@]+\z/}.sample(20).join }

  it 'should exist' do
    job = build(:job, title: nil)
    job.valid?
    expect(job.errors[:title].size).to eq(3)
  end

  it 'passes regex rules' do
    job = build(:job, title: bad_string)
    job.valid?
    expect(job.errors[:title].size).to eq(1)
  end
end
```